# Pyqt - Weird Rendering sizing results when rendering Qgraphicsscene using Qprinter

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am rendering a QGraphicsScene and running into strange results, ideally I am looking to render one page of the scene at a time the code I am using is below:

```
def print_widget(self,widget, filename):
    printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution)
    printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.OutputFormat.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName(filename)


    ps = QPageSize(QPageSize.PageSizeId.Tabloid)
    print(printer.setPageSize(ps))
    printer.setPageOrientation(QtGui.QPageLayout.Orientation.Landscape)
    printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(.25,.5,.25,1),QPageLayout.Unit.Inch)

    dpi = printer.resolution()
    page = printer.pageRect(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.Unit.DevicePixel)

    painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
    scaleX = widget.width()/page.width()
    scaleY = widget.height()/page.height()
    #percent the widget takes up the page
    print(scaleX)
    print(scaleY)
    
    target = page
    one_page = scaleY*widget.height()
    iterations = 1
    scanning = True
    while scanning == True:
        source = QRectF(0,(one_page*(iterations-1)),widget.width(),(one_page)*iterations)
        widget.render(painter,target,source,QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
        printer.newPage()
        iterations +=1

        if iterations ==4: scanning = False

    painter.end()
```

Essentially it just iterates through the page size and moves the source down by a page size accordingly, the 4 iterations is just a way to test. Firstly, my graphics scene render is cutting off the "entries" as I call them before the foreground( which I used to draw the squares). Second, although the source size remains constant, the scaling between pages seems to shrink. I cannot figure out an explanation for this behavior and would appreciate any help. I especially do not know how to deal with the foreground issue shown below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQURi.png)

EDIT: I fixed the rendering issue with the foreground by using a full pages instead of margins, which is fine for my needs.. What I cannot understand is that if the source size stays the same for every iteration, why would the render size between pages be different?

Comment: The height of the page shouldn't change. By doing `source = QRectF(... (one_page)*iterations)` you're increasing the page height at each iteration, and `render()` will then "scale" the contents to fit the increased height. Just do `source = QRectF(0, one_page * (iterations - 1), widget.width(), one_page)`. Other notes: consider starting `iterations` from 0 (which is more consistent) and just use `while True:` and `break` to exit the loop; 2. you should use the scene as reference with its [`sceneRect()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop) to get the correct coordinates for ->

Comment: -> the painting (or, eventually, the [`itemsBoundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#itemsBoundingRect), so that you always ensure that the whole scene is actually painted, without unnecessary margins (or clipping content); 3. it's normally better to use the [`QGraphicsScene.render()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#render) function, not that of the graphics view; 4. you can ignore the `painter.end()` in this case, since it's at the end of the function and it's just a local object, it will be ended anyway as soon as it's garbage collected.